# C++ How to add two vectors asynchronously

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, stdvector

Good morning everyone.

I am new to C++ 11 multithreading theme and trying to write down a code that add two vectors of equal sizes in asynchronous way.
This means, if I have two vectors:

```
vector<int> fisrt = {1, 2, 3};
vector<int> second = {3, 2, 1};
first += second; // first = {4, 4, 4}
```

I wrote Paginator class which splits vector on "pages" with appropriate page_size. 
My idea of vectors addition in asynchronous way is next: split vectors on pages with choosen page_size, and add pages of first and second vectors in asynchronous way.

**Paginator class implementation**

```
template<class Iter>
class IterRange {
public:
    explicit IterRange(Iter first, Iter last) : first_(first), last_(last) {}

    Iter begin() { return first_; }
    const Iter begin() const { return first_; }

    Iter end() { return last_; }
    const Iter end() const { return last_; }

private:
    Iter first_;
    Iter last_;
};

template<class Iter>
IterRange<Iter> MakeIterRange(Iter first, Iter last) {
    return IterRange<Iter> {first, last };
}

template<class Iter>
class Paginator {
public:
    Paginator(Iter first, Iter last, size_t page_size) : page_size_(page_size) {
        size_t pages_count = static_cast<size_t> (floor((double)distance(first, last) / page_size_));
        pages_.reserve(pages_count);

        size_t page_id = 0u;
        Iter begin_page = first;
        for (page_id, begin_page; page_id < pages_count; ++page_id, begin_page += page_size_) {
            pages_.push_back(MakeIterRange( begin_page,  begin_page + page_size ));
        }

        // If some elements less than page_size_ is left
        if (begin_page != last) {
            pages_.push_back(MakeIterRange(begin_page, begin_page + distance(begin_page, last)));
        }
    }

    auto begin() { return pages_.begin(); }
    auto begin() const { return pages_.begin(); }

    auto end() { return pages_.end(); }
    auto end() const { return pages_.end(); }

private:
    size_t page_size_;
    vector<IterRange<Iter>> pages_;
};

template<class Iter>
Paginator<Iter> MakePaginator(Iter first, Iter last, size_t page_size) {
    return{ first, last, page_size };
}

template<class Container> // And the same for non constant Container
auto Paginate(const Container & c, size_t page_size) {
    return MakePaginator(begin(c), end(c), page_size);
}
```

This Paginate procedure is used in operator+= in my Matrix class.

Matrix class fields are:

1. Matrix sizes along Ox and Oy direction respectively: **size_t nx_**, **size_t ny_**.
2. Vector of (nx_ * ny_) size, which stores all elements in matrix: **vector body_**.

**Operator += for Matrix**

template
    inline Matrix & Matrix::operator+=(const Matrix & other) {

```
size_t threads_numb = thread::hardware_concurrency();
size_t page_size = static_cast<size_t> (ceil((double)body_.size() / threads_numb));
    vector<future<void>> futures;

    auto page_1 = page::Paginate(body_, page_size);
    auto page_2 = page::Paginate(other.body_, page_size);

    auto it_2 = page_2.begin();

    for (auto it = page_1.begin(); it != page_1.end(); ++it, ++it_2) {
        futures.push_back(
            async([it, it_2] { transform(it->begin(), it->end(), it_2->begin(), it->begin(), plus<T>()); })
        );
    }

    return *this;
}
```

But as a result I get **iterator out of range** error! How could I fix this?

P.S. Sorry for  bad representation of first string in operator +=. Could not fix this problem :(

Comment: Don't see anything immediately obvious, will keep looking. Your use of `trunc((double)...` seems pointless, as distance should fit in a ssize_t anyway? Also, if your aim is to avoid physical page boundaries, are you sure that your vector data is aligned to those boundaries? If not, you may be better chopping your jobs into equal(er) sizes less than your ideal size, rather than have one small job at the end?

Comment: You may also be better splitting based on the number of available processors, rather than a page size?

Comment: Another detail `begin_page + distance(begin_page, last)` mixes 2 concepts. Distance allows that you might have non-random iterators, and the code might be slower, but + does not allow non-random iterators. How is this answer not `last` anyway?

Comment: I am assuming you have already checked the two matixes are the same size?